# How to create SOAP web service in Java, which connects to Oracle Stored procedure and gives result back as a web service response

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am new to Java Web Services, I need to create a SOAP web service which takes some input and connects to Oracle Stored procedure and gives the result back as a web service response.

Can you please help with any article or blog to fulfill my requirement?

Thanks in advance !!!
George

Comment: This seems like a pretty broad question.  If you have tried something you can share some specific problem you face.

Comment: Thanks for your response Sid. I am following this approach and trying to include DB call to invoke the Oracle Procedure.

https://www.journaldev.com/9123/jax-ws-tutorial

Can you help me where exactly I can add JDBC call?

Answer (score 0):

3 easy steps:

1. Learn how to write a SOAP web service. Look at JAX-WS tutorials, or libraries like [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/). Decide whether you are going to go contract first (WSDL first) or code-first. Contract First recommended. Decide whether you want to use a framework like Spring.
2. Learn how to call a stored procedure from Java. Look at JDBC tutorials.
3. Combine them together.

Note: SOAP is old and clunky. You might want to look at JSON-based REST web services before you learn something that is getting old and increasingly out of fashion.

Comment: Thanks for your response Jbx. I am following the approach in the following link and trying to include DB call to invoke the Oracle Procedure. journaldev.com/9123/jax-ws-tutorial Can you help me where exactly I can add JDBC call?

Comment: In the implementation. So in that example it would be `PersonServiceImpl` .

Comment: Thanks for your input jbx. I will try it.